# Binding WCF ObservableCollection to Silverlight DataGrid

Tags: silverlight, datagrid, wcf-binding

I have a silverlight Datagrid populated from a stored procedure from database using a duplex WCF service, which the service pushes a new set of ObservableCollection to the client every 20s. Right now, my client Datagrid itemsSource is reset to the new ObservableCollection everytime the new one comes in. I'm just wondering if it is possible to DIRECTLY BIND the itemsSource of the datagrid to the WCF service ObservableCollection  so that I don't have to reset the source everytime and the UI would be automatically updating when INotifyPropertyChanged is fired from the service ObservableCollection.

I tried the solution in this post http://forums.silverlight.net/t/216796.aspx/1  but it's not exactly what I want since it still resets the itemsSource everytime.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you mean INotifyCollectionChanged and not INotifyPropertyChanged? If you are simply rebinding each time, you might as bind to a List<T> instead.

Answer (score 0):

Create an ObservableCollection property to bind to. When your service updates, Clear this collection and add all of the elements of the list from the service, or go through and add/remove only those that need changing.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I've tried this and it's still not the ideal solution I want beacause Clearing the collection first and adding a new one is still the same as resetting the datasource. In terms of "go through and add/remove only those that need changing" , right now I have a for loop which compares the old collection with the new collection and update the old one, but it is not very efficient. Do you have any better way of doing this?

Comment: sicccccc, you will need to ask yourself, which is more efficient, clearing the collection and adding the new items, or the for loop you mentioned which is not very efficient.

Comment: Hi dparker, what I really want to know is that if there is any better alternative solution that I could update my observablecollection dynamically from the service. Do you have any suggestions? I want to avoid clearing and Adding the new collection to my datagrid source because it would make my datagrid to lose its current view.

Comment: Is there an actual problem, or is this a purely theoretical issue? If it's an actual problem, the solution may be to rework the service to only provide the elements that need to update.

Comment: It is an actual problem, so how can I make the service to only provide the elements that need to update? Could you be more specific please?